# Accessing AWS_CREDENTIALS within an application served by express.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I have a React application which is served by express.js. There is a component/library within the react application which is trying to use the aws-sdk for s3/cloudwatch functions.

My issue is that the aws-sdk fails to find credentials when the application runs. They are stored in an ~/.aws/credentials file, which operates correctly for other applications.

I've found that if instead of calling these methods directly in my application, I call a custom express route which calls them from my server.js, there is no credentials error.

I'd very much prefer not to have these additional routes and call my own application to perform these functions. Is there a fundamental concept I am mi-understanding here? Is there a for the application served by express to be able to read the filesystem correctly and read the credentials file?

Comment: Are you trying to make this a client-side call? Express apps should be able to make the calls just fine (server-side), but react never should be able to (client-side).

Comment: Thanks @Dan Crews for your comment, that's correct I thought it would be cleaner to have a method to call some application code outside of React (from react) rather than POSTing data back to the server continuously. But I see your point, this should not be done and I will have to settle for a lot of requests back and forth.